# Is it possible to use beer taps to control water to a faucet?

Tags: equipment

For my basement bar, I would like to mount 2 beer taps (1 hot, 1 cold) to the wall. Water would come out a faucet just like a normal sink. You would pull the beer tap to turn on water, with temp adjusted based on how far open hot water or cold water taps are pulled. Hope this makes sense. Ideas appreciated!

Comment: I think this is a pretty cool idea for a home bar.  Just to be picky, taps are devices that attach beer serving lines to a keg.  Faucets are the things that the beer comes out of.  I know everyone uses the terms synonymously but they aren't the same.  So you want to install beer faucets for water faucets in your house.  Could be important when searching for parts or the like for this project.

Comment: Finally a good use for these Bud Light handles I've been seeing on ebay!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with actual brewing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be better off using a single handle Delta faucet and making an adapter so you could mount a beer tap handle to it so you get the effect you are looking for but with a device designed for what you are doing (dispensing hot, cold and warm water at various flow rates). There are other brand single handle faucets, but Delta is the first one that came to mind.

Comment: yeah I'd just try and make it look like a beer tap, without violating the important principals of plumbing code

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Instead of normal faucets you want to use beer taps! :)

Temperature of the water coming out of the tap cannot be controlled by how far you pull the tap, only the speed at which the water will be dispensed.

If you want temp to be controlled by the tap, you will have to have an inline heater/cooler that will be electronically connected (somehow) to the tap to determine how far the handle is pulled down. This will probably have to be custom built. BUT: I am sure if you google for the *very* fancy bathroom accessories you will find a company that already does this, and then you can ask them to make a tap for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Not recommended.

Most house pressure is 25+ psi which could auto open a standard beer faucet or perlick style.

I think a stout tap would hold the pressure but they are expensive.

A standard shaft style (not perlick) would start to stick from hard water in a short amount of time.

But most importantly, most municipal water companies require water saving aerators which taps don't have.

Answer (score 0):

At UBrew in Bermondsey, London, UK they have used beer taps as the faucets in the bathrooms, only cold so no temp control issues but they work well and are a nice novel touch. If you were to have a pre mix on the hot then you could likely get away with cold and warm, but I would avoid using just hot unless you don't have very hot water in your house; as without flow control someone may scald themselves.